# Start Anaconda from specific env

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda

Having trouble to start Ananconda from particular env
I use zsh shell on macOS Monterey

1. Create env: conda create -n DC python=3
2. (DC) conda activate DC
3. (DC) anaconda navigator
4. zsh: command not found: anaconda
   Before that i did install some packages via: (DC) conda install numpy
   Anaconda easy start from base at the same time.
   Maybe i do not understand how it works? Maybe it Anaconda Navigator can only start from base.

Answer (score 3):

In your third line, you are missing `-`. It should be like this.

```
anaconda-navigator
```

Comment: Thank you, but this is not the case.